# Net::SFTP::StatusException with CarrierWave on delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, net-sftp

I'm trying to call `event.destroy` on an event in my app. Each event has an uploaded image using carrierwave. When I try to destroy an event that has had an image uploaded, and then the event gets edited and a new image gets uploaded I get returned the error `Net::SFTP::StatusException (2, "no such file")`.

Any clue how to fix this? Nothing special is happening, just a simple image upload using carrierwave and carrierwave-sftp to upload it to an external server. When the event is destroyed I have a callback referencing a custom method (below) to remove the image.

Thanks SO!

event.rb model

```
after_destroy :delete_event_image

def delete_event_image
  self.remove_image!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless carrierwave-sftp is breaking this feature somehow, carrierwave already does this for you [out of the box](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb#L30).